# check if some folders exists java Android

Tags: java, android

I need check at least 4 directories if they exists and get the correct path in a variable for finnish my code.

But I don't know the correct way to do that.

Thanks for your help.

Here my code for check a single directory

```
final String uploadFilePath = "/mnt/sdcard/folder1/";

   File f = new File(uploadFilePath);

    if(f.exists() && f.isDirectory()){
        Log.v("FILES", "EXIST");
    }else{
        Log.v("FILES", "DONT EXIST");
    }
```

Comment: store all the paths in a array, Iterate over the array and find the correct path you needed

Comment: you will have to have a loop for it there is nothing new

Comment: your log says files exists but not file its directories exists

Comment: ALSO: you should replace "/mnt/sdcard/folder1" with Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + file.seperator + "myFolderName";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way you can go on

```
String[] myDirectories = {"","",""......}; // your list of directories

for (String directory : myDirectories ) {
  File file = new File(directory);
   if(file.exists() && file.isDirectory())
      // Do something you have found your directory

}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to check both if `exists()` and `isDirectory()` ?
I mean what if we use any one of them ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this enough?

```
Path uploadPath = Paths.get(uploadFilePath);
Path path = Files.exists(uploadPath) ?  uploadPath : Files.createDirectory(uploadPath);
System.out.println(path);
```

Then to check for the N directories, put it in a loop maybe.

```
final String[] paths = { "C:/aa/", "C:/bb/", "C:/cc/", "C:/dd/"};
for (String path : paths) {
   Path uploadPath = Paths.get(path);
   if(Files.exists(uploadPath))
       Files.createDirectory(uploadPath);
   System.out.println(uploadPath);
}
```

Comment: Note Path is only in Java 7. You can sometimes get problems in android with 7